# Connecting pys60 bluetooth console

Tags: python, symbian, pys60

I'm trying to program using python (pys60) in my phone.
i'm using two way to connect my ubuntu 10.10 to my phone using bluetooth console
first is:
    sdptool add --channel=2 SP
    mknod /dev/rfcomm0 c 216 0
    rfcomm listen 0 2
and the second is:

```
    hciconfig reset
    hcitool dev
    sdptool add --channel=2 SP
    rfcomm listen rfcomm2 2
```

Both first and second way work well for connecting to myphone
so i get this in my ubuntu terminal

```
    Connection from 00:1D:FD:91:1A:EA to /dev/rfcomm2
    Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

The problem is, i cant get into the python shell in the phone from my terminal.
When i'm using

```
    cu -l /dev/rfcomm2
```

what i get is

```
    cu: /dev/rfcomm2: Line in use
```

so i try to use

```
    screen /dev/rfcomm2
```

but still i failed

```
    Cannot open line '/dev/rfcomm2' for R/W: Device or resource busy
    Sorry, could not find PTY.
    [screen is terminating]
```

Wish someone could tell how to resolve this, moving the *.py to phone every time i want to test the script is so tiresome.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo cu -l /dev/rfcomm2
```

If it works you will probably understand what is wrong

**[EDIT]**

```
sudo chown root:root /dev/rfcomm2
```

the line is not in use in my case (try sudo fuser /dev/rfcomm2) cu is a little buggy in error detection see [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=145459).

The thing i still don't understand is why `screen` does not work.